Python venv creation fails due to ensurepip and zlib issues
I'm unable to create a Python virtual environment via venv in which I can install dependencies via pip. These issues occur on a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
I specifically want to use Python's built-in venv (not any other variants), so I run the command: python3.12 -m venv myvenv. This partially creates the venv directory but fails midway (doesn't create bin/activate) with the message:
Error: Command '['/sample/path/myvenv/bin/python3.12', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
As per this answer, I've tried installing python3.12-venv via sudo apt install python3.12-venv, which successfully installs but doesn't change the error.
Venv creation does succeed if I run it with the --without-pip flag, and I can install pip independently via sudo apt install python3-pip, but actually using pip in the newly-created and activated venv gives me an "externally-managed-environment" error and instructs me to use the pip in myenv/bin/pip, which doesn't exist because I specified the --without-pip flag.
Running the failing command directly (python3.12 -m ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip) results in a stack trace that complains "No module named 'zlib'" and "can't decompress data; zlib not available." I followed the directions in several other answers and ensured that packages were installed successfully, via sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev (as well as build-essential and the non-dev version of zlib), but the command still fails with the same "zlib not available" error. My zlib is version 1:1.3.dfsg-3.1ubuntu2.
I also tried building Python from source to see if it would resolve the problem, but the same zlib issue persists. I followed the official developer's guide for installing dependencies, and this also didn't resolve the zlib error.
Will fixing the zlib issue allow me to use venv, and if so, what am I missing? I've been stuck on this for hours -- any help is appreciated!

This question is similar to: Can't fix "zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available" when I type in "python3.6 get-pip.py". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Fundamentally, ensurepip (which venv uses to put Pip into new venvs) requires zlib support; you'll need a Python that's built with it. Simply installing the zlib support packages (system packages via Apt) doesn't solve the problem; you need to rebuild Python to use them. If python3.12 refers to the system-provided Python then you have an OS support issue, not a programming question.

"but actually using pip in the newly-created and activated venv gives me an "externally-managed-environment" error and instructs me to use the pip in myenv/bin/pip" - you aren't "using it in" the environment; being "in" the environment is a shallow illusion created with some environment variables and setting the prompt. If you installed system-level Pip and don't have another one, then pip will invoke that system-level Pip. By default, Pip installs for the environment that it appears in.

You can use the system-level Pip to install into your virtual environment - see for example Pip install python package into a specific directory other than the default install location. The simplest way is probably with the --python option in newer Pip versions.
